# youtube in background mode in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview, youtube

I'm using https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper for implement Youtube videos in my iOS Project.

I implement the YTPlayerView object in Appdelegate; in my ViewController I execute the view. Really YTPlayerView, is a UIView that show an UIWebview.

The proble occure when I want to listen the webview (Youtube Music) in background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
       [self.playerView playVideo];
}
```

I implement this in Appdelegate but the first time I dismiss the app, the music is set in background, but the second time no and I don't know why.

I have seen so many apps at app store that u can make this, so is possible but I don't have seen anything about it.

Thanks

Comment: you should remove the app from running in the background. If you can't remove the app completely,you can't play the music in the app delegate